# set a value to xml

Tags: android

Using sharedpreferences I save a value. I need to set this value (duration) to xml file. How I resolve?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
   android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="1500" />
```

Comment: It is not possible to modify the contents of Android resource files at run-time.

Comment: Huh? I need to create 4 fadein.xml and put a different value?

Comment: You'll need to use a different XML file depending on the preference

Comment: I've an array.xml with 4 items. Users choose a duration (500,1000,1500,2000) this value goes to sharedpreferences. What is best way to resolve?

Comment: @PolHallen : You can either use 4 XML files and use a switch/case block to choose which one to use based on the preference or, as xBroak suggests, change the duration at run-time using Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your animation code use :

```
Animation alphaAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animate);
YOURVIEW.startAnimation( alphaAnim ); 
alphaAnim.setDuration(VALUE);
```

Comment: ok thanks! I've 2 xml: fadein.xml and fadeout.xml. With activities I use: overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein,R.anim.fadeout). Now, in your code, "YOURVIEW" what should be? thanks!

Comment: Ok, but with 2 files (fadein.xml and fadeout.xml)?

Comment: This cant be really used for activity transitions, more so widget animations